# next_run_by_calendar_string HH24:MI format

Tags: sql, oracle

It is possible to write calendar string which one returns only this times (HH24:MI): 3:50, 8:40; 15:50; 20:40?
I tried:

```
select next_run_by_calendar_string('Freq=DAILY;ByHour=3,8;byminute=50,40;bysecond=0;')
from dual;
```

but it returns 3:40, not 3:50 (only).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution, **BYTIME** clause in **DBMS_SCHEDULER**, Oracle Database 12.2 documentation.

```
select next_run_by_calendar_string('Freq=DAILY;BYTIME=35000,84000,155000,204000;')
from dual;
```